The specified selector is not loading in Apify
I'm building an Apify scraper to target transaction data on a dynamic webpage. The table containing these transactions loads asynchronously via AJAX, taking under 30 seconds.
This is the page when loading:

This is the fully loaded page:

This is my code:
// Import required modules
import { Actor } from 'apify';
import { PuppeteerCrawler } from 'crawlee';

await Actor.init();

const input = await Actor.getInput(); 

const startUrls = [
    { 
        url: 'https://www.example.com/24horasinternetPj/Login', 
        userData: { label: 'LOGIN_PAGE' } 
    }
];

// Create a proxy configuration if needed
const proxyConfiguration = await Actor.createProxyConfiguration();

const crawler = new PuppeteerCrawler({
    proxyConfiguration,
    requestHandlerTimeoutSecs: 180, // Increase the timeout
    requestHandler: async ({ page, request, log }) => {
        log.info(`Processing ${request.url}`);

        if (request.userData.label === 'LOGIN_PAGE') {
            log.info('Navigating to the login page...');
            await page.goto(request.url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0', timeout: 60000 });
            
            // Step 1: Login form
            log.info('Filling out the login form...');
            await page.type('#vcedula', input.ruc);
            await page.type('#vcuenta', input.cuenta);
            log.info('Submitting the login form...');
            await Promise.all([
                page.click('#rwb_login_Siguiente'),
                page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0', timeout: 60000 }),
            ]);
            log.info('Login form submitted. Navigated to password page.');

            // Step 2: Password input
            await page.waitForSelector('#InputValuePIN', { visible: true });
            log.info('Filling in password...');
            await page.type('#InputValuePIN', input.password);
            await page.click('#rwb_login_Siguiente'); // Adjust if needed
            log.info('Password submitted. Logged into the system.');

            // Step 3: Navigate to the account extract page
            const extractPageUrl = 'https://www.example.com/24horasinternetPJ/Cuentas/Extractos?NumeroCuenta=1&TipoCuenta=ca&Fecha=12-2024&DayRango=-1&YearRango=2024&MonthRango=12';
            log.info('Navigating to the account extract page...');
            await page.goto(extractPageUrl, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0', timeout: 60000 });
            log.info('Navigated to the account extract page.');

            // Debug cookies
            const cookies = await page.cookies();
            log.info('Cookies:', cookies);

            // Debug redirections
            page.on('framenavigated', frame => {
            log.info(`Navigated to: ${frame.url()}`);
            });

            // Wait for dynamic content
            page.on('response', async (response) => {
                if (response.url().includes('_ByFecha')) {
                const jsonData = await response.json();
                log.info('Captured AJAX Data:', jsonData);
                }
            });

            // Check for iframe or direct content
            const extractContainer = await page.waitForSelector('.extracto-container', { visible: true, timeout: 120000 });
            if (!extractContainer) {
                console.log('Extract container not found. Checking iframes...');
                const frames = page.frames();
                for (const frame of frames) {
                    console.log(`Frame URL: ${frame.url()}`);
                }
            }

            // Log final content
            const html = await page.content();
            log.info(html);

            // Step 4: Scrape transactions
            log.info('Scraping transactions...');
            const transactions = await page.evaluate(() => {
                const rows = document.querySelectorAll('table tbody tr');
                return Array.from(rows)
                    .filter(row => !row.classList.contains('extracto-background-color')) // Exclude unwanted rows
                    .map(row => {
                        const cells = row.querySelectorAll('td');
                        return {
                            fecha: cells[0]?.textContent.trim() || '',
                            comprobante: cells[1]?.textContent.trim() || '',
                            concepto: cells[2]?.textContent.trim() || '',
                            debito: cells[3]?.textContent.trim() || '',
                            credito: cells[4]?.textContent.trim() || '',
                        };
                    });
            });

            log.info(`Scraped ${transactions.length} transactions.`);

            // Save transactions to Apify's default dataset
            await Actor.pushData(transactions);
        }
    },
    failedRequestHandler: async ({ request, error, log }) => {
        log.error(`Request ${request.url} failed too many times. Error: ${error.message}`);
    },
});

await crawler.run(startUrls);
await Actor.exit();

This is the log:
2024-12-17T12:43:24.754Z WARN  PuppeteerCrawler: Reclaiming failed request back to the list or queue. Waiting for selector `.extracto-container` failed: Waiting failed: 120000ms exceeded
2024-12-17T12:43:24.757Z     at async PuppeteerCrawler.requestHandler [as userProvidedRequestHandler] (file:///home/myuser/src/main.js:71:38) {"id":"xkqrXSpzJ7KUaaJ","url":"https://www.example.com/24horasinternetPj/Login","retryCount":1}

The .extracto-container selector consistently fails to be found with a waitForSelector timeout of 60 seconds. I suspect the issue lies in identifying the correct element to wait for before scraping the transaction table.
What strategies can I employ to pinpoint the optimal element to trigger the wait logic, ensuring the scraper captures the fully loaded transaction data?
I tried mulitple selector ids, without success.

@ggorlen I have added all the code from Apify, thanks.

Thanks although https://www.example.com/24horasinternetPj/Login isn't an actual site, so it's still not really possible to help here.
